# Magento 2 Compile Generation Does Not Exist

Tags: magento2, admin, setup-di-compile, crud

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0

> C:\wamp\www\magento2>C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.19\php.exe bin/magento
>   setup:di:compile

```
Compilation was started.
%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 48.0 MiB%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 48.0 MiBProxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 48.0 MiB
Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 50.8 MiB
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 50.8 MiB


  [RuntimeException]
  Source class "\Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\PostsInterface" for "Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\PostsRepository" generation does not exist.


setup:di:compile
```

I'm trying to create Custom Admin CRUD.

Comment: Did you declare class `Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\PostsInterface`?

Comment: the first thing that comes to mind is that your php ini is not set to have enough memory/time to execute the command. Have you tried running this commend with the verbose flag - `bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvvv` ?

Comment: what part of this error message leads you to think that it's an issue with memory?

Answer (score 1):

First you should run upgrade command and check your custom module has  registered successfully. After that you should go for compilation.

Make sure /pub/static and /var folders have proper write permission (777).

Comment: It's Windows so no issues permission wise

Answer (score 1):

Issue should be in the construct function. Either the arguments before  array $data = [] needs to have some changes done, or the variables before parent::__construct($data); have some issues. You should post your code of constructor function.

**Less reputation not allowing to comment**

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace the Magento/Vendor folder from fresh copy.
2. Assign the permissions
3. Remove Var/Generation folder
4. And compile again

This issue also occured for 2.1.5. Just replace the vendor folder